# Best place for logic for calculated default values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

Building React Redux application I am wondering where to put dependency selection logic. I checked questions about business logic and there are advices to use reducer, action or selector.

Selectors seems to best fit, but I need this calculation before I update store and this usage is anti pattern.

App have filters which I want to add to store via action creators, but before adding to store I would like to calculate default values which will be rendered after store changes.

I have some dependent select options:

```
const fields = [
    {value: "Name", title: "Name", type: "string"},
    {value: "Date", title: "Date", type: "date"},
    {value: "DateTime", title: "DateTime", type: "datetime"},
    {value: "Alive", title: "Alive", type: "check"}
];

const conditions = [
    {value: "is", title: "Is", types: ["string"]},
    {value: "contains", title: "Contains", types: ["string"]},
    {value: "from", title: "From": types: ["date", "datetime"]},
    {value: "between", title: "Between": types: ["date", "datetime"]},
    {value: "checked", title: "Checked": types: ["check"]},
];
```

Life cycle is:

```
1. Get first available field
2. Get first available condition for this field (field.type exists in conditions.types)
3. Set/Format default value according to field and condition
4. Add to store and render in UI
```

When I add filter to store I would like to get default values set like this:

```
[{
    field: "DateTime", // <--  Calculated default value
    condition: "Between", // <--  Calculated default value
    // Value property structure is calculated as well
    value: [{
        dateStart: "<There goes calculated default value>",
        timeStart: "<There goes calculated default value>",
        dateEnd: "<There goes calculated default value>",
        timeEnd: "<There goes calculated default value>",
    }]
},{
    field: "Name", // <--  Calculated default value
    condition: "Contains", // <--  Calculated default value
    // Value property structure is calculated as well
    value: [{
        string: "<There goes calculated default value>",
    }]
}]
```

Which are the best place to put such logic in action creator or reducer or somewhere else? And which approach/plugin fits best?

Comment: Those are called side effects. You need a side effect library (I'm using Redux Saga) or you can learn more here: https://ricostacruz.com/til/redux-side-effects

Comment: Can you present some example, please?

Comment: Actually, I think that I can create `selector` in `action` with `redux-thunk` and then `dispatch` new value when I got calculation done.